# C++ Input Overloading stuck in while loop

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

So basically in C++ i am trying to input multiple Objects into a Vector using operator overloading. In  my main ( ) i have a while loop which reads the books in from a text file then stores them in the following strings:

```
 String name, title, pages, classcode, status;
```

I then go to create my Book object:

```
Book b(name,title pages,classcode, status);
```

After doing this i then use cin to input the object into my vector using the operator overloading.

```
cin >> b;
```

my overloading function looks like this :

```
istream &operator>>( istream  &input, Book &b )
  { 


input >>  b.classCode;
input >> b.author;
input >> b.title;
input >> b.status;
input >>  b.numPages;


 return input;
 }
```

I am trying to use operator overloading to store the objects into a vector of  but everytime i run the program it will only store one Book object.

Comment: `cin >> b;` doesn't "store the object into a vector". It reads the object from standard input. This would overwrite the object's attributes, so it doesn't seem like you want that because you said you read them from a file already.

Answer (score 2):

To store multiple instances of `Book` in a `std::vector<Book>` you can write the following code:

```
std::vector<Book> v;
Book b;
while (std::cin >> b)
    v.push_back(b);
```